# Can I completely replace Profiles with Permission sets

Tags: managed-package, permissions, permission-sets, custom-profile

I have a managed release package which is having one custom profile. Now in next release I want to create a new profile in V2.0 of released package. But what I found is while upgrading package, I can not upgrade any profiles. So for all existing customer with 1.0 of released package, I can not map the new profile and none of the permissions will be added to package upgrade.

I read permission sets are upgradeable . Can anyone please confirm instead of using a new profile with all permissions, i can create a basic profile and add rest of permissions through permission set.

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score -2):

Sure you can do this. As per my understanding Profile is super set of permission. And  permission set are kind of exception is security model. In your scenario it make seance to create a base profile and give all permission using permission set.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but just want to confirm if it should work with package upgrade as well I assume..? The main problem is I can not upgrade any package and add new permissions to included profiles

Comment: Are you 100% sure that they are not up-gradable?  Check this link https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm&language=en_US

Comment: @user2451 Did you got chance to verify this?

Comment: why Down vote guys?

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 It depends upon the way you upgrade your package. We are using push upgrades - in this case profiles are not upgradable at all. But if the package is upgraded by direct url, where you could specify mapping between package profiles and subscriber profiles, in that case profiles are upgraded but only with permissions of newly introduced objects in that package version (changes in permissions re existent objects and fields are not reflected). Permission sets are better in such cases, but there are e.g. admin permissions (view dashboards etc.), which can not be upgraded at all.