# Assign managed package profiles to clients profiles after installation

Tags: managed-package, profile, package-install

As one of the first step during managed package installation it asks to map profiles from managed package (actually they call it profile settings, since profiles from managed package are not installed in clients org directly) to real clients profiles.

Is there any possibility to map profiles later, sort of to bring up that dialog again? What if I need to introduce new profile in the system after package has been installed - how should I map it?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to permission sets for the managed package?

Comment: @crmprogdev Nope, profiles in managed package, which basically exists only during installation time.

Comment: related: [Can I completely replace Profile with Permission sets](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47667/can-i-completly-replace-profile-with-permission-sets)